# Pseudo metric space $d(x,y)= x+y$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Can I say that $d(x,y)= x+y$ is pseudo metric?

I am confused because if I put $d(1,1)=2$ not $0$ so it is not pseudo.

But some say that it is pseudo because I can put two distinct numbers and get $0$ like $d(-1,1)$ which is zero so it is pseudo but not metric.

Can you help me please?

Comment: At least in the [standard definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space) a pseudo metric must still satisfy $d(x,x)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: I think you're missing absolute value

Comment: no the question is without absolute value

Comment: Well, a pseudo metric is only allowed to take non-negative values, so that's another disqualifier for this one.

Comment: so it is not pseudo metric?

Comment: Note that you didn't even specify the underlying set. If $X=\{0\}$, then $d(x,y)=x+y$ does indeed define a metric. Please be more specific in your question.

Comment: sorry its my first week of taking metric spaces and online so I did not practice so much

Comment: but i wanted to ask about this exercise because my dr said its pseudo

Comment: There is no such thing as "being pseudo".

Answer (score 3):

You make it sound like "pseudo" and "metric" are two independent properties a map $d\colon X\times X\to\mathbb R_{\ge 0}$ could have. That is not the case. There is a definition for what a [metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) is and a definition for what a [pseudometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudometric_space#Definition) is.

As you can see from the definitions, the only difference is that a metric is required to satisfy $d(x,y)>0$ for $x\neq y$ while a pseudometric might have $d(x,y)=0$ for some $x\neq y$.

Both of them must satisfy $d(x,x)=0$ for all $x\in X$ so your candidate is neither a metric nor a pseudometric.

Note that every metric is a pseudometric but not every pseudometric is a metric.

Comment: yes this is what I was thinking about but my doctor told me its pseudo because when you put two distinct values -1 and 1 I get 0 as you said above"while a pseudometric might have d(x,y)=0 for some x≠y."

Comment: @LamaBitar It still needs to satisfy $d(x,x)=0$ for all $x\in X$ to be called a pseudometric. Tell that to your doctor.